# How can I force content_tag_for to use dashes instead of underscores when making the element's id?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using jQuery-UI's tabs, which don't seem to like the `content_tag_for` method of joining the record with the id using an underscore. Is there a way to force `content_tag_for` to use dashes instead of underscores without redefining `content_tag_for` in my application helper with some nasty gsub? Here's my code as it is.

```
  <ul class="ui-tabs-nav">
    <% @preview_articles.each do |article| %>
      <%= content_tag_for(:li, article, 'nav-fragment', :class => "ui-tabs-nav-item #{'ui-tabs-selected' if article == @preview_articles.first}") do %>
        <%= link_to image_tag(article.photos.first.image.url(:thumbnail)), "#fragment-#{article.id}" %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
```

I need that li tag to have an id of nav-fragment-article-id whereas `content_tag_for` is creating an id like nav-fragment-article_id.

Any suggestions on getting jquery-ui's tabs to work with underscores are welcome, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can monkey patch [`ActionController::RecordIdentifier`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RecordIdentifier.html), like so:

```
module ActionController
  module RecordIdentifier
    JOIN = '-'.freeze
  end
end
```

Just stick this into an initializer somewhere and you're good to go, even though it'll generate a warning because the constant was defined before.

Comment: I thought about that, but was concerned about breaking other parts of the application. Could an override like that be action specific?

Comment: No worries, it shouldn't break anything (and never has, for me)